# Make a class comprises of the functions like UIAlertView, UIActivityIndicator and call them back in various viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, function, viewcontroller, alertview

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class classViewController: UIViewController {
  // The function i want to call in other view controllers..
  func alertView(title: String, message: String) {
    var alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in                
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

In the other view controller, where I've made an `IBAction` to perform this alertView, I have done this:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
  classViewController().alertView("title", message: "message")
}
```

When I run the app, after tapping the button I get this error, but no `alertView`:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

Right. If you want to make a global class that displays alerts, you need to pass in a reference to the current view controller, and use that instead of "self" in calls like `presentViewController`.

Your class should probably not be a subclass of UIViewController, since it looks like you're never displaying it to the screen.

I created a `Utils` class that is a subclass of `NSObject`.

It has a method `showAlertOnVC` that looks like this:

```
  class func showAlertOnVC(targetVC: UIViewController?, var title: String, var message: String)
  {
    title = NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "")
    message = NSLocalizedString(message, comment: "")
    if let targetVC = targetVC
    {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
      let okButton = UIAlertAction(
        title:"OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        handler:
        {
          (alert: UIAlertAction!)  in
      })
      alert.addAction(okButton)
      targetVC.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
      println("attempting to display alert to nil view controller.")
      println("Alert title = \(title)")
      println("Alert message = \(message)")
    }
  }
```

Comment: u got the question correctly..sorry i am a beginner.. can u elucidate it more??

Comment: i called this function in the IBAction in "viewController" like this..
Utils.showAlertOnVC(ViewController(), title: "title", message: "message")

still getting the same error :/

Comment: That's because that is wrong. Your code is creating a new instance of a view controller and passing that to the method. That's wrong. You should call my method from your view controller, and pass in self.